# Angular + Spring boot integration is it possible?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have an Angular UI that communicates with the Spring Boot application using REST. Now I want to integrate Angular and Spring Boot. I can think of two .

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a place to ask for help in fixing bugs, not really for advice.

Comment: Off topic for SO. But just out of curiosity, what do you mean by integrating angular and spring-boot? Do you want to deploy their code together to a server? If yes, use maven frontend plugin to build angular code and add the compiled code to the war which contains the spring boot code.

Answer (score 0):

We can Integrate both in single context.
By implementing Web Application Intializer in spring boot application.